# difference between timestamps and nullableTimestamps in Laravel 5.4 migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

According to [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#columns):

- `$table->timestamps();`      Adds nullable `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.
- `$table->nullableTimestamps();`  Nullable versions of the `timestamps()` columns.

I don't understand. In other words, what I read is:

- `A` creates nullable columns
- `B` is like `A` but it creates nullable columns

What did I miss?

Comment: They recently changed the timestamps to be nullable by default, I think this is a mistake in the documentation and thus indeed the two are currently equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.2 there is no difference. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L829) you'll see that `nullableTimestamps()` is an alias for `timestamps()`

```php
/**
 * Add nullable creation and update timestamps to the table.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function timestamps()
{
    $this->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
    $this->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
}

/**
 * Add nullable creation and update timestamps to the table.
 *
 * Alias for self::timestamps().
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function nullableTimestamps()
{
    $this->timestamps();
}
```