# Add nullable timestamps columns for existing entries via migration in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a table with data and I want to add nullable timestamps using migration. I had added timestamps which used current timestamp. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between timestamps and nullableTimestamps in Laravel 5.4 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442888/difference-between-timestamps-and-nullabletimestamps-in-laravel-5-4-migration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a migration with following code

```
$table->nullableTimestamps();
```

It will add nullable time stamps to your table.

Comment: plus this one https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns